# SQL server 2005 setup issue. (with SSIS)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to install sql server 2005 sp 2 x64 bit edition,after selection i am getting
below error.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Setup

None of the selected features can be installed or upgraded. Setup cannot proceed since no effective change is being made to the machine. To continue, click Back and then select features to install. To exit SQL Server Setup, click Cancel.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.1399.06&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=SQLSetup90&EvtType=28108

---

Please let me know how to resolve this issue and complete the installation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to some earlier version / edition component already being installed on your machine.  If this is the case then the only way I've ever been able to get around this is to manually uninstall the component via the Add / Remove Programs control panel.

Usual suspects for me have been:

- MSXML6
- BOL (this *shouldn't* matter, but has for me in the past)
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server Compact Edition (various components)
- SQL Server Native Client
- Various other client tools - i.e. other versions of Management Studio (Express, for example)
- Backward compatability components
- 32-bit versions of anything you're trying to install